# Recreate zfs pool for a reinstalled os

Tags: zfs

I need to replace disk for a zfs root installed system.

Previously it was (before reinstalling OS for test purpose which is also I want to accomplish after install):

Created mirror with zpool attach rpool /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb

```
NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    rpool       ONLINE       0     0     0
   mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
      sda2      ONLINE       0     0     0
       sdb      ONLINE       0     0     0
```

And I reinstalled OS:

```
NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    rpool       ONLINE       0     0     0
      sda2      ONLINE       0     0     0
```

sdb holds data...

```
    pool: rpool-12312656247996879599
     id: 12312656247996879599
    state: DEGRADED
 status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.
 action: The pool can be imported despite missing or damaged devices.  The
        fault tolerance of the pool may be compromised if imported.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
 config:
        rpool-12312656247996879599  DEGRADED
          mirror-0  DEGRADED
            sda2    FAULTED  corrupted data
            sdb     ONLINE
```

And I want to create mirror and sync data from sdb to current mirror after reinstalling OS. After reinstalling OS, I have one rpool and one sdb pool seperatly. I can send/recv data on two pools and destory sdb pool and attach to rpool and make mirror. But wondering is there any way without manually syncing files (send/recv) and attach sdb which is in pool to rpool without destroying it?

Answer (score 1):

You have taken your disk `sda2` out of the old pool, erased its content and installed a new pool (with your new system) on it. As this was a redundant vdev (mirror), you essentially have two different pools, each having one disk (meaning no fault tolerance). You still have both options - using the new one or restoring the old one:

---

**If you want to discard your old pool and use your new install (`sda2`), follow [these steps](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gkdep/index.html):**

- Format your disk `sdb`, deleting all data on it
- Attach the formatted disk to your new pool: `zpool attach rpool sda2 sdb`
- Wait for resilvering to complete, check with `zpool status rpool`
- Copy over boot sector data so the system can boot from both disks (assuming you use GRUB): `installgrub /boot/grub/stage1 /boot/grub/stage2 /dev/rdsk/sdb`

---

**If you want to discard your new pool and return to your (degraded) old pool (`sdb`):**

- Shut down the system and physically remove your disk `sda2`
- Start the system, it should now recognize your old pool as a valid bootable root pool (only works if you have added the boot sector to this disk previously, similar to steps above, otherwise you will get a boot error)
- Physically reconnect your disk `sda2` to the system and format it
- Attach your disk `sda2` to your old pool: `zpool attach rpool sdb sda2`

---

If you have a Solaris/illumos system, you could (in the future, not in this case) also use `beadm` to perform upgrades, tests and recovery in-place (inside the same `rpool`, but on different snapshots). This way, you can revert without giving up redundancy temporarily.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am managing server remotely. So can not physically touch disks. Only remotely reinstall OS. So first desc is for me but I want to keep data on sdb and mirror it with new rpool. So by reinstalling OS, I have at the end two different pools. So only option I found is, I send/recv between two pools. And do what you wrote at first option. Is there any other option without needing to send/recv files? Like without destrying pool and attaching it to rpool and make mirror.

Comment: @OzgurErdogan Instead of removing the disks, it could be enough to disconnect them virtually (on Solaris, use `cfgadm -c unconfigure` and `cfgadm -c disconnect`). For the rest of your question, could you edit your original question and explain in more detail what you want to do and what to avoid? Generally, `send/recv` is painless and fast, you might not save much time in avoiding it.

Comment: I added more details. So to make it short; can I attach sdb to rpool after reinstall without destroying/formatting sdb? So I can keep data on sdb and after attaching it it can mirror data to rpool.